# The Image type for a Virtual Machine Scale Set may not be changed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-vm-scale-set

I already have a VMSS provisioned with a base setup of Centos OS on linux. I created an image with my custom image setup (software, applications,etc) and I am run ARM script to update the VMSS, however it fails with

```
"error": {
"code": "OperationNotAllowed",
"message": "The Image type for a Virtual Machine Scale Set may not be changed."
```

}

Is it possible to update the image without deleting the VMSS and recreating?

Comment: Have you changed the Image reference publisher and offer in the template?

Comment: yes under storageprofile "imageReference": {
              "id": "[variables('managedImageId')]"
            },

Comment: The two properties just could be set when it be created, they could not be modified, see [Properties with restrictions on modification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#create-time-properties)

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Can you update the VMSS with your custom image through CLI or PowerShell command?

Comment: Any update? Do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can reimage from your custom image1 to the custom image2 as long as images have same publisher and the same offer

Answer (score 1):

Basically what Joy Wang pointed out in the comments, some properties can only be set at creation time:

1. Availability Zones
2. Image reference publisher
3. Image reference offer
4. Managed OS disk storage account type

there are several other quirks, you should read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#create-time-properties

Answer (score 0):

The Image reference publisher and offer properties just could be set when it be created, they could not be modified.

See: [Properties with restrictions on modification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#create-time-properties)

If you use the custom image, you can update the image by updating the `imageReference ID`, also can use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesets/createorupdate), [Powershell and CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#update-the-os-image-for-your-scale-set).